# Tuple vs hard coded string

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples

We have this code at our work, which i wanted to know the difference between it and just manually typing out the same thing.

```
const tuple = <T extends string[]>(...args: T) => args;
const strings = tuple(
  'blabla',
  'default',
  'standard'
);

export type Strings = typeof strings[number];
```

When i hover over "Strings", it basically is `type Strings = 'blabla' | 'default' | 'standard'`

My question is, why not just simply type out the samething?

```
type Strings = 'blabla' | 'default' | 'standard';
```

Instead of all the tuple stuff? I can't see a difference, but if someone could explain why we're using this Tuple function that would be great

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask someone who works with you why they did that? How is anybody else supposed to know?

Comment: A benefit I can see is that you have an array of all the values that you can use at runtime, whereas just hardcoding with `|` you just get the compile-time type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't export `strings` then it is definitely better to directly declare the type. In some cases you also need the values though, and using that `tuple` function saves you from having to specify each one twice.

There's a simpler and safer way to do this though:

```
export const strings = [ 'blabla', 'default', 'standard' ] as const;
// type: readonly ["blabla", "default", "standard"]

export type Strings = typeof strings[number]
// type Strings = "blabla" | "default" | "standard"
```

This makes `strings` readonly, so you can't do an unsound `strings.pop()` for example.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/AQ4UwDwBwewJwC7AMYwHYGclbgSzQOYbAC8wA2sAOQBGANgIb0NUA01AJmAGYMCudBG2pYGaDgzgcqwALrAGxVJgQBuAFChgAem1b9IAHoB+dZtCRYiYAgCeUMMADKCPIWJk7DmN2A58RORofAC2NGBwsuYgugZaJkA)